# NSMutableArray and pointer: an operation on the pointer is an operation on the original array (?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, pointers, nsmutablearray, datasource

This is kind of a long way to go to ask a simple question, but given how confusing pointers in Objective-C are for some, maybe verifying what's going on here will help others, as well as myself.

So, in a nutshell, I have a UITableView whereby you can enable editing and delete a row. I want to delete the row from the table view, and the data source(s). The original data source is in a model class, but I have a pointer/property containing the data in my local table view controller. When I delete a row from the table view via editing, it appears to work and delete the data...but I don't understand why. I think it's because of my fundamental misunderstanding of pointers.

In my model class with an NSMutableArray:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *allAlarms;
// ... plist gets read and serialized to an array ...
allAlarms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[plistValues objectForKey:@"Alarms"]];
```

In a UITableViewController class, I pull that mutable array in via a property during viewWillAppear:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *alarms;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // retrieve values from data controller
    self.alarms = [dataController returnAllAlarms];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

When the delegate method for editing is exercised, I do this, and it works...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the local data source
    [self.alarms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    // The above line appears to delete it in the local pointer as well as in the original property in the model class
    // so I just have to tell the data controller to save plist for when it's read back in via viewWillAppear
    [dataController writePlist];
    // Delete the row from the table view
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

}

Why does what is going on in my tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath ultimately work? Does removing an item from a pointer to an NSMutableArray in my local class also remove it in the original pointer in the remote class because the former is a pointer to the latter?

I need to understand because there are other operations I'll be performing on this local pointer and want to make sure I'm not being redundant in wanting to perform it on the remote property, etc. Is there anything about what I'm doing unintuitive and redundant, or will it make more sense as I continue to learn Objective-C & use pointers more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you don't quite understand how pointers work. Rather than trying to explain it all myself, I'll point you to this [thorough chapter on pointers](http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html#Pointers).

One thing to note is that in Objective-C, you never allocate objects on the stack<sup>1</sup>. Objects are always allocated on the heap, and a pointer returned to you. (like `malloc()`.) This is why there is always an asterisk (`*`) in the type of an object<sup>2</sup>. Both your model and controller have pointers to the same underlying array. `self.alarms = [dataController allAlarms]` doesn't copy the array, it copies the *pointer*<sup>3</sup>.

When you call `removeObjectAtIndex:`, it doesn't change anything about the pointer—a pointer is just a number—it *dereferences* the pointer and operates on the underlying object in memory.

<sup>1.</sup> With one minor exception, Blocks.
<sup>2.</sup> Excluding `id`, which is `typedef`'ed.
<sup>3.</sup> If you *do* want to copy the array, use the `(copy)` property attribute rather than `(retain)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference (and I will read it) but I misunderstand pointers despite all the textbook reading, so I figured I'd just dive in and try. But I think I (basically, sort of) get what you're saying: so both these pointers just reference the same array. By creating a pointer to a pointer, I'm just referencing the same array. And a removeObjectAtIndex on either pointer will remove the object from the same array. Using retain just said "give me ownership of that same object in memory." Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yep, you've got it. Just a few corrections on terminology: When you set `self.alarms`, that's not a pointer to a pointer. It's a copy of a pointer. (a pointer to a pointer looks like `NSError **`) Or another way to think about it, it's a copy of a number. The same thing happens when you assign, say, an int to an int. (`int i = 5, j = 3; j = i;`) If you were using `i` and `j` as array indices, setting `j` to `i` doesn't set `array[3]` to `array[5]`. It just changes the value of `j`. Returning to pointers, the `int`s are your pointers and `array` is all of memory.

Comment: This is starting to make sense. Thanks a lot for your help.